# Переменные типа bool

Tags: c++

Поясните пожалуйста как работают переменные типа bool в С++ с использованием циклов и условий.

Answer (score 2):

Трудно придумать хороший пример, который всё объясняет. Такой пример

```
bool var = true;
int count;

while (var) {
    count = count + 1;
    if (count > 100)
        var = false;
}
```

Цикл выполняется пока var true. Счётчик с каждым разом растёт, и однажды if сработает (count > 100) и установит var в false и тогда цикл прекратит выполняться.